# how to pull the data after a specified type from one variable by an id in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set like below and i want to pull the rows after "de" in "chart_status" after sorting by id and then date(posixct) in ascending order.

data

```
id      date         chart_status
1234    2015-01-12   u
1234    2015-01-13   ap
1234    2015-01-16   cr  
1234    2015-01-14   de  
1234    2015-01-17   ap
1234    2015-01-15   de
3456    2015-01-12   cr  
3456    2015-01-13   de  
3456    2015-01-14   u  
6789    2015-01-18   de
7456    2015-01-16   u
7456    2015-01-17   ap
7456    2015-01-18   de
```

I want to sort the above data frame by id and then date("POSIXct format"),and i want to pull the rows after "de" from "status" variable.

Expected output:

```
id      date         chart_status
1234    2015-01-16   cr   
1234    2015-01-17   ap
3456    2015-01-14   u
```

Tried:

```
  factors = unique(data$id)  
  final_data = NULL  
  for(i in 1:length(factors)){    
  data = data[data$id == factors[[i]],]      
  data = data[order(data$id, data$date),]  
  data = -data[data$chart_status == "de",]  
  final_data = rbind(final_data,data) 
  }
```

please help me in finding the solution for this using R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
#order the data
data<-data[order(data$id,data$date),]
#get the elements after "de"
data[as.logical(
       ave(as.character(data$chart_status),data$id,
        FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)>match("de",x) & x!="de")
     ),]
#    id       date chart_status
#3 1234 2015-01-16           cr
#5 1234 2015-01-17           ap
#9 3456 2015-01-14            u
```

Comment: i tried to order the data using above command, but it is not,because the date  format is in POSIXct format, i am getting the following error :              Error in `-.POSIXt`(data$date) : 
  unary '-' is not defined for "POSIXt" objects

Comment: Where did you find the minus (`-`) sign in my command? My solution works for the example in the OP. Share your data and the actual commands you gave.

Comment: Thank you, it's working, but it is not when i am trying to order in descending order.

Comment: To order increasing by `id` and decreasing by `date`, try: `data[order(data$id,-as.numeric(data$date)),]`